# Ternary operator in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I can write in java

```
int i = 10;
String s = i==10 ? "Ten" : "Empty";
```

Even I can pass it in method parameter.

```
callSomeMethod(i==10 ? "Ten" : "Empty");
```

**How do I convert it to kotlin?** Lint shows error when writing same thing in kotlin.

Answer (score 8):

```
callSomeMethod( if (i==10) "Ten" else "Empty")
```

Discussion about ternary operator:
https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/ternary-operator/2116/3

Comment: Kotlin provide many shortcuts than Java, but now it fails.

Comment: This is actually the standard syntax in FP languages, where flow-control constructs are expressions that can be evaluated. If you think Kotlin chases opportunities to provide "shortcuts" that replace four characters with one, no, that has never been Kotlin's goal.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of

```
String s = i==10 ? "Ten" : "Empty";
```

Technically you can do

```
val s = if(i == 10) "Ten" else "Empty"

val s = when {
    i == 10 -> "Ten"
    else -> "Empty"
}

val s = i.takeIf { it == 10 }?.let { "Ten" } ?: "Empty"

// not really recommended, just writing code at this point
val s = choose("Ten", "Empty") { i == 10 } 
inline fun <T> choose(valueIfTrue: T, valueIfFalse: T, predicate: () -> Boolean) = 
    if(predicate()) valueIfTrue else valueIfFalse
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create an extension function with generic for boolean value

```
 fun <T> Boolean.elvis( a :T, b :T ): T{
     if(this) // this here refers to the boolean result
         return a
     else
         return b
}
```

and now you can use it for any boolean value (cool Kotlin)

```
//                                         output
System.out.print((9>6).elvis("foo","bar")) foo
System.out.print((5>6).elvis("foo","bar")) bar
```

[Extensions in kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html)

Comment: This is a nice answer. But I will use `if else` way. Cause `char counts` are almost **same**, and I will not add extension to do same char count code.

Comment: @Khemraj thanks and thanks to you, I got the chance to play a little, I totally respect and agree with your decision , happy coding :)

Comment: By the way, thanks for sharing extension info. I am new to kotlin & appreciate your way.

Answer (score 1):

As the original question was using the term 'Elvis operator' it may be a good idea to provide a short comparison with the ternary operator.

The main difference between ternary operator and Elvis operator is that ternary is used for a short if/else replacement while the Elvis operator is used for null safety, e.g.:

- `port = (config.port != null) ? config.port : 80;` - a shortcut for an if/then/else statement
- `port = config.port ?: 80` - provides a default value to be used in case the original one is `null`

The examples look very similar but the Ternary operator can be used with any type of boolean check while the Elvis operator is a shorthand for `use config.port if it's not null else use 80` so it only checks for `null`.

Now, I think `Kotlin` doesn't have a ternary operator and you should use an `if` statement like so - `s = if (i==10) "Ten" else "Empty"`