# Ternary Conditional Operator in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, ternary-operator

**What is the equivalent of this expression in Kotlin.**

```
a ? b : c
```

This is giving error.

Comment: Oh dear... typing exactly that into your favorite search engine delivers tons of results, one of which is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16336500/kotlin-ternary-conditional-operator (which was probably also highlighted while you entered your question) ... actually it is an "exact" duplicate...

Comment: I feel like I answered this question like 8 hours ago https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51779334/ternary-operator-in-kotlin/51782206#51782206 and even that was a duplicate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Kotlin, if statements are expressions. So the following code is equivalent:

```
if (a) b else c
```

Hope it's working for you.